Confusing tab UI in Nautilus/Files Manager

The currently displayed window forms a single and continuous visual/color space with inactive tabs. Like in the example above, the user sees the content/folders of the sys directory, whereas the UI suggests that the user looks at Documents tab, which is misleading
I am trying to get used to it but often find myself pausing for a moment trying to figure out which tab is actually active.
Other applications, such as Terminal, don't have this problem, as an active tab has a a bright underline (see image below) making it obvious which tab is active. In Chromium web browser, the current window forms a continuous visual space (using color and thin borders) with the active tab.
Is there any way to change the look of Gnome Files to provide a stronger visual clue for active tabs?


What does it look like if you open three tabs at once?

It doesn't matter how many tabs are open. The problem is that the currently displayed window forms  a single and continuous visual/color space with inactive tabs. Like in the example above, the user sees the content/folders of the sys directory, whereas the UI suggests that the user looks at Documents tab, which is misleading.

I feel the same issue here.
Both browsers and terminal deal with active tab with shadows or colors arount the active border, not changing the color of the whole tab.
Nautilus should work the same way. The way it is now is super confusing.
